# Download "10yard.zip" with wget, not "10yard.zip/"

Tags: download, wget

I'm trying to download all the zip file from a page in archive.org using `wget`:

```
wget -r -np -nc -l 1 -A zip https://archive.org/download/mame-merged/mame-merged/
```

I have found the previous command in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13574050/68571).

I don't want to download a zip file if it is already downloaded using the argument `-nc`.

But when `wget` downloads the file `100lions.zip`, I see that it downloads its 5.2M, but I can't find that file. I only found an **EMPTY** folder with the name 100lions.zip.

This is the wget output when it downloads that file:

```
--2022-01-30 09:01:07--  https://archive.org/download/mame-merged/mame-merged/100lions.zip
Connecting to archive.org (archive.org)|207.241.224.2|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://ia801502.us.archive.org/13/items/mame-merged/mame-merged/100lions.zip [following]
--2022-01-30 09:01:08--  https://ia801502.us.archive.org/13/items/mame-merged/mame-merged/100lions.zip
Connecting to ia801502.us.archive.org (ia801502.us.archive.org)|207.241.228.152|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5405543 (5,2M) [application/zip]
Saving to: 'archive.org/download/mame-merged/mame-merged/100lions.zip'

archive.org/download/mame-mer 100%[=================================================>]   5,15M   268KB/s    in 29s

2022-01-30 09:01:38 (184 KB/s) - 'archive.org/download/mame-merged/mame-merged/100lions.zip' saved [5405543/5405543]

--2022-01-30 09:01:38--  https://archive.org/download/mame-merged/mame-merged/100lions.zip/
```

I think the problem is that there is a link on that web page for each zip file named `View Contents` that points to a folder with the same name that the zip file. For example, for the file `100lions.zip` there is a link `View Contents` that points to the folder `100lions.zip`.

I have seen that wget, first download the zip file, and the it deletes it to create an empty folder with the same name.

This is the source code for the zip and the folder links:

```
<td><a href="10yard.zip">10yard.zip</a> (<a href="10yard.zip/">View Contents</a>)</td>
```

I want to download the first `a href`, not the second one.

Is there any way to avoid download the empty folder?

Comment: That content appear to be available on github, why not try to get it that way instead... start reading at https://www.mamedev.org/

Comment: @Hannu Because this is not the question. I want to know how to download it with `wget`.

Comment: I can understand that, the above seems easier though ;-)

Comment: I think they're doing something at the archive.org site to thwart ppl from doing this. They have a page that describes bulk downloading - https://blog.archive.org/2012/04/26/downloading-in-bulk-using-wget/. Normally when I want to download that archive.org URL I'd make use of a torrent client. They provide a .torrent file in that feed as well for this express purpose - https://archive.org/download/mame-merged/mame-merged_archive.torrent.

Comment: BTW check out torrent CLIs here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200540/command-line-tool-for-a-single-download-of-a-torrent-like-wget-or-curl.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure they're detecting click and sending the ZIP file when you click a single file in a browser, but when `wget` walks the tree it's seeing those ZIP files as links to follow (b/c that's what they actually are in the UI) and is going down into the contents vs. pulling the actual ZIP file.